# How to display the result of a Select SQL statement in a subform of access with VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, subform

I don't know why is too difficult to display a `SELECT` statement in a subform using VBA, in VB is too easy show data in a `DataGridView`.

"Type Mismatch" error appears in line `Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = qdf` when I run the code.

This is the full code:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim qdf As New DAO.QueryDef
Dim pSQL As String

pSQL = "SELECT * FROM Seguimiento"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Consultasql", pSQL)

Me.DGVResultado.SourceObject = "Seguimiento"
Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = qdf
Me.DGVResultado.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Recordsource property of a form requires a string, not a querydef.

You could either use:

```
Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = qdf.name
```

OR

```
Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = pSQL
```

OR

```
Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = qdf.sql
```

Comment: Thank you, the "type mismatch" was solved, but now shows a new error "Run-time error 2467 the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist" in line:

    Me.DGVResultado.Form.RecordSource = pSQL

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to put a form into the "Subform" control that you have on your form.  I'd suggest asking another question about this as i) this may not be the (whole) issue and ii) if it is, a complete explanation of the issue is beyond the scope of this particular question.